# How do I call the functions of the parent class from an instance of a subclass?

Tags: php, oop, subtype, supertype

normally, (in subtype definition) I use

```
function enable() {
  parent::enable();
 }

 function disable() {
  parent::disable();
 }
```

and then I call $subtypeinstance->enable()

but can I also use something like

```
$subtypeinstance->parent::enable()
```

or

```
(SupertypeName)$subtypeinstance->enable()
```

Comment: I doubt that what you're trying to do is possible, even if it is I'm having some trouble in thinking up a situation where you'd benefit from doing this.

Comment: @GordonM it'd be useful when you don't wannt to override functions of supertype in each of the subtypes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually call `Parent::enable()` or `parent::enable()` (i.e. class name or `parent` keyword) as PHP makes no distinction between static and instance calls and passes an instance anyway.

```
class Foo {
    public $x;
    public function bar() {
        echo "Foo::bar(), x is " . $this->x . "\n";
    }
}

class FooChild extends Foo {
    public function bar() {
        echo "FooChild::bar(), x is " . $this->x . "\n";
        Foo::bar();
        parent::bar();
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->x = 42;
$foo->bar();

$fooc = new FooChild();
$fooc->x = 43;    
$fooc->bar();
```

Output:

```
Foo::bar(), x is 42
FooChild::bar(), x is 43
Foo::bar(), x is 43
Foo::bar(), x is 43
```

The [parent keyword reference](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php) explains this and gives the same example.

Comment: For the record, I don't think this actually answers @Uğur's needs and still misses the point of inheritance.

Comment: Oh, you're right; I must've focused on the title. (And the title is why I will not delete this answer.) Well, the actual question does not make sense, then. One can simply use a different function name in the parent and call it when it needs to be called.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment:

> it'd be useful when you don't wannt to override functions of supertype in each of the subtypes

If all your method does is call the method of the same name of its `parent`, you don't need the function at all. Functions are *inherited* from the parent class, that's mostly the whole point of inheritance.

```
class Parent {
    public function enable() {
        echo 'enabled';
    }
}

class Child extends Parent { }

$child = new Child;
$child->enable();  // outputs 'enabled'
```

So I suspect you don't actually need what you're asking for. Otherwise, I don't think it's possible.

Comment: netbeans instellisense does not recognize the functions in superclasses like that. they are recognized with parent:: only.

Comment: in php documentation i have not seen any usage like that either. I am still looking.

Comment: however, using $this->method calls the supertype methods with no need for overriding parent functions in subtypes.

Comment: Well, that's the way inheritance works though. Otherwise there'd be little point to it. It's well documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

Comment: @Uğur Netbean's Intellisense isn't very intelligent if it doesn't recognize this most basic part of inheritance. I strongly recommend you try again to understand why and how this works, otherwise you're using inheritance wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that

```
$this->function()
```

calls the supertype methods with no need for overriding parent functions in subtypes

Comment: Because of the way inheritance works, exactly as laid out in my answer. It doesn't matter whether you call it from a method within the object through `$this` or from "outside" the object. A child class automatically ***inherits*** all of the parent's methods and properties. *"Overriding"* means that you explicitly *redefine* an existing parent method.